# Can I name my variable 'public' in Java for JSON serialization/deserialization?

Tags: java, gson, naming-conventions

So I'm working with a public API that sends me a JSON object with a boolean field named 'public'.

```
{  
    ...
    "public" : true,
    ...
}
```

I'm using GSON to parse this into a Java class, but this forces me to declare the following variable, which of course the Java lexer/parser does not agree with:

```
private boolean public;
```

Is there any way to allow my variable to be named `public`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use Gson's [`@SerializedName`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) annotation.

```
@SerializedName("public")
private boolean someOtherName;
```

You can't use the word `public` (or any of the other reserved keywords) as an identifier name in Java source code.

Most feature-rich JSON parsers will have such an annotation or other mechanism for naming JSON keys, which don't have as many naming restrictions.